# How to branch Mono so main process is on null and error-like process when hasElement?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am trying to make sense of reactive paradigms, but the logic appears counter to my needs.

The situation is the early stage of a registration process: start with registration data, check if an account exists for the supplied email (getting back either an `AccountDto` or `null`) and processing from there. With an imperative approach, this is easy; branch on `account == null`. But with a reactive paradigm, I can't make sense of it.

If I were processing the `account` and substituting something in for the `null` case, that would be fine. But in this instance, it's effectively inverted: when I get back `null` – i.e. no account exists – I want to do the main processing to create the account, whereas when it is not `null`, I want to use the error-equivalent fallback.

The only approach I've found that will work is first use an imperative branching to wrap reactive elements, per:

```
public ResponseDto registerAccount (RegistrationDto data)
  ResponseDto responseDto = new ResponseDto ();
  if (accountExists(data.getEmail()) {
    // return responseDto with account-exists error messaging
  } else {
    // create the account, send verification email, etc
    // return responseDto with information that verification is sent
  }
}

public boolean accountExists (String email) {
  return retrieveAccount(email)
      .hasElement().block(); 
}

public Mono<AccountDto> retrieveAccount (String email) {
  // calls db service; returns either the Mono-wrapped AccountDto or Mono-wrapped null.
}
```

Given that I am being pushed down the reactive path, I would rather avoid this hybrid approach.

How do I process the result where the main body of processing depends on the `Mono` being empty and the equivalent of an error state is when it has contents to process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just one `flatMap` away from the reactive path:

```java
public Mono<ResponseDto> registerAccount(RegistrationDto data) {
    return retrieveAccount(data.getEmail())
        .hasElement()
        .flatMap(accountExists -> {
            if (accountExists) {
                // return responseDto with account-exists error messaging
            } else {
                return createAccount(data);
            }
        });
}

public Mono<AccountDto> retrieveAccount(String email) {
    // calls db service; returns either the Mono-wrapped AccountDto or Mono-wrapped null.
}

private Mono<ResponseDto> createAccount(RegistrationDto data) {
    // create the account, send verification email, etc
    // return responseDto with information that verification is sent
}
```

Comment: Consider returning ResponseDto with error msg instead of:


`Mono.error(new AccountAlreadyExistsException()); `

Comment: @kokodyn fair point, replaced with the comment from the question

Comment: Thanks both. (I wish the documentation were even half as clear as your answer.)